# How to get trialDuration of a product in RevenueCat?

Tags: ios, swift, storekit, revenuecat

I am trying to dynamically display the trial duration of my annual product. I have found `trialDuration` in RC framework but I don’t know to use it. I am getting products like this:

```
private var offering: Offering? = SubscriptionManager.shared.offerings?.current
```

and then need to access the trial duration to display it via a text label. something like getting `localizedPriceString` for product price.

Any help would be great!

Comment: I'm looking for the same thing.  Any luck?

Comment: @Daniel no! I am loading it manually from a URL on my website

Answer (score 3):

I'm using the sk1Discount which is part of the StoreProductDiscount type.

For example use the following code snippet:

```
if let introductoryDiscount = package.storeProduct.introductoryDiscount {
    if let offer = introductoryDiscount.sk1Discount,
       introductoryDiscount.paymentMode == .freeTrial {
        Text("\(offer.subscriptionPeriod.numberOfUnits) \(offer.subscriptionPeriod.numberOfUnits > 1 ? offer.subscriptionPeriod.unit.localizedPluralString : offer.subscriptionPeriod.unit.localizedString) for free!")
    }
}
```

Hope that will help you. Note: I experienced that the sk1Discount is sometime in debug mode empty, but I never experienced any problems in production.

Answer (score 3):

**RevenueCat SDK v4.21.1+**

The `localizedPriceString` property is available for convenience on each `Package` object, and on Apple's App Store, free trials are provided as an [introductory offer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/in-app_purchase/original_api_for_in-app_purchase/subscriptions_and_offers/implementing_introductory_offers_in_your_app#3149466).

You can also create your own `trialDuration` property using the underlying storeProduct of StoreKit.

```swift
let discount = package.storeProduct.introductoryDiscount
```

Here's an implementation that returns a custom string representation of the trial period:

```swift
var introOfferDuration: String? {
    guard let discount = package.storeProduct.introductoryDiscount else {
        return nil
    }
    return discount.price == 0
    ? "\(discount.subscriptionPeriod.periodTitle()) for free"
    : "\(package.localizedIntroductoryPriceString!) for \(discount.subscriptionPeriod.periodTitle())"
}

// MARK: - RevenueCat SDK

extension SubscriptionPeriod {
    var durationTitle: String {
        switch self.unit {
        case .day: return "day"
        case .week: return "week"
        case .month: return "month"
        case .year: return "year"
        default: return "Unknown"
        }
    }
    
    func periodTitle() -> String {
        let periodString = "\(self.value) \(self.durationTitle)"
        let pluralized = self.value > 1 ?  periodString + "s" : periodString
        return unit == .week ? "\(self.value * 7) days" : pluralized
    }
}
```